# Proof of König - Egerváry theorem.

Tags: combinatorics, proof-writing, proof-explanation

> > $\underline {\textbf {König - Egerváry Theorem}}$ $:$
> >
> > Consider a $(0,1)$ matrix $A$. Then the minimum number of lines (either horizontal or vertical) required to cover all the $1$'s of $A$ is equal to the maximum number of $1$'s in $A$ no two of them on a line.

Our instructor has given us a proof of the above theorem by considering a mimimum covering of all the $1$'s of $A$ by $r$ rows and $s$ columns where both of $r$ and $s$ are positive. The proof is relatively simple which uses Hall's theorem. But my question is how can I ensure that neither $r$ nor $s$ is zero? It may so happen that one of them is zero. Then how do I prove the theorem? Please help me in this regard.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Well, $r=0$ and $s=0$ are equivalent and saying that there are no ones in $A$. In this case both numbers in question are zero.

Comment: But it may so happen that $r=0$ but $s \neq 0$ or $r \neq 0$ but $s=0$. Then what can we say?

Comment: If $r=0$, it must be the case that $s=0$, as $r=0$ implies that you don't need a single row to cover the 1s in $A$ (i.e., there aren't any 1s in $A$ to begin with). If $r$ is nonzero, then $s$ must be as well, by the same logic.

Comment: Consider the matrix \begin{pmatrix} 
1 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & 1 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 0 \\                                 
 0 & 1 & 1                                     
 \end{pmatrix} Here $r=0$ but $s \neq 0$.

Comment: Look my definition of $r$ and $s$ and then comment.

Comment: This is tagged [tag:proof-explanation], but it doesn't actually include the proof you want explained. If you included your instructor's proof it would be useful context and might get you better answers.

Comment: I have finally proved it on my own.